# R.id suddenly unrecognize Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, r.id

I was worked about my project a few hours today, and suddenly all the "`R.id...`" was unrecognized. all the R is in Red color, and when I put the mouse on it say

> Cannot resolve symbol R

I was tried to delete all the changed (with ctrl+z on all the pages) but nothing fixed. 
its not a specific item, is all the "`R.id..`" codes that I have in the project, in all the activities and fragments.
what can I do? where is the problem? can i restore my job somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your Xml file. If there is an error then you can't resolve this error.

Else :

Click on **Build -> Rebuild** Project and then click **Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.**

Comment: Thanks! I follow your introduction and its really worked now!